# Analyzing entire code before executing in C++

Tags: c++, c, function, recursion

Quick question about the order in which functions are executed. My code looks like the following:

```
int values()
{
'code'
motors();
}

int motors()
{
'code'
values();
}

int main()
{
values();
}
```

After it reads main() and runs values(), it's not aware of motors() so it doesn't run it (I think). I can't put it before values() either because then it wouldn't be aware of values(). So what could I do to prevent the problem?

Comment: infinite recursion, stack overflow...

Comment: You should get you jargon sorted. The C++ compiler doesn't run code, it compiles it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just provide the declarations, and define the functions afterwards.

```
//declarations
int values();
int motors();

//definitions    
int main()
{
   values();
}

int values()
{
   motors();
}

int motors()
{
   values();
}
```